# How to make newtonian particles to not go through each other?

Tags: particles

Right now it just looks more like fluid, and the objects are going trough each other a little bit like this:

[image: objects]

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question you can use the Cast Modifier

Make 2 sphere

[image]

Select 1 sphere and add Cast Modifier and Target to other sphere

When you move the 1st sphere it goes inside the other.